# MySQL insert on an empty table takes 38.91ms

Tags: mysql, percona

This DB is running in a cluster.

Insert/Update queries are taking more than 30ms to execute. Select queries are quick with less than 5ms.

We are already following this guide: [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/28/10-mysql-performance-tuning-settings-after-installation/)

From Laravel Query Log time is in (ms):

```
array (
    'query' => 'insert into legacy_item_requests (request) values (?)',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
      0 => 1,
    ),
    'time' => 38.91,
  ),
```

Direct Insert in MySQL:

[image]

Show create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `legacy_item_requests` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `request` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

The insert is happening on an empty table which is puzzling.

We are using: Server version: 5.7.28-31-57 Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL), Release rel31, Revision ef2fa88, WSREP version 31.41, wsrep_31.41

Laravel 9.9.0
PHP 8.0.18

My question here is how do I diagnose this and figure out what's causing the slow insert/update?

Note that this insert is part of a big transaction and I can't do BEGIN and COMMIT because it causes a deadlock due to the sheer size of the transaction.

I can provide config details if needed

Show Profile Result

[image]

[image]

On a different MySQL server the insert took 0ms so we're wondering what's the difference considering the one with the 39ms is a bigger server. What other factors will affect the insert query?

Comment: `Inserts` being a modification are required to be durable, hence requiring a waiting of acknowledgement back all the way from hardware to indicate it has been stored. So being slower than `select` is expected. Deadlocks happens if the acquisition of locks is in a different order. Maybe there is some way to optimize the large transaction.

Comment: Tested on MariaDB-10.6, admittedly the 3 nodes where all local, and got [this profile for the same query](https://gist.github.com/grooverdan/15101063919fdd83c9d08ebd253cd406). I'd suggest taking it to percona to see if they can improve that region of code. Or consider a MariaDB migration.

Comment: @danblack what is initiating replication for? tried googling it but can't find any reference.

Comment: It would be [in the code](https://github.com/percona/percona-xtradb-cluster/tree/Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-5.7.28-31.41-2) probably under `PSI_stage_info` or similar, I can't find it right now. What it exactly is would involve understanding the code up until the next stage. You may be able to map the concept to [this galera certification flow](https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/certification-based-replication.html).

Comment: How far apart are the Galera nodes?  (That is, ping time.)

Was this `INSERT` the first after a reboot?  If so, possibly there are some one-time startup actions.  Or does the Laravel Insert repeatedly take a long time?

Answer (score -3):

Might be that you have too many indexes, or redundant indexes. You can use tools like EverSQL.com to find these indexes.

You can also run `select 1;` to see if you have any network latency.

*Disclosure, I am the co-founder of EverSQL*

Comment: We require disclosure when you promote a product you are affiliated with see https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/promotion. Please read that page carefully before posting again.

Comment: Redundant non-unique indexes do not slow down `INSERTs`; they go into the "change buffer" for eventual storing on disk.